# Replacing many missing columns in a Data Frame using a function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, replace, mapply

I have a categorical dataset with hundreds of columns, with missing values. I'm trying to write a function that can do this fast, but am running into issues. Here is what I have done so far. Pointers are greatly appreciated:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50,60),
  gender=c('male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female', ''),
  mood=c('happy', 'sad', 'happy', 'sad','happy', ''),
  outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0,1),
  province = c('gp', 'np','ec','', 'wc', 'nw'))
```

I want to be able to to do this for every variable:

```
print("before")
df %>%
count(gender)

levels(df$gender) <- c(levels(df$gender), "Unknown")

df <- df %>% 
    mutate(gender = replace(gender, gender == "", "Unknown"))

print("after ")
df %>%
count(gender)
```

And my attempt at implementing this in a function is as follows, where I have a function that takes in one variable at a time:

```
valueFiller <- function(myVar){
    print("before")
    df %>%
    count(myVar)

    levels(df$myVar) <- c(levels(df$myVar), "Unknown")

    df <- df %>% 
        mutate(myVar = replace(myVar, myVar == "", "Unknown"))

    print("after ")
    df %>%
    count(myVar)
}
```

Then I was going to apply to many columns this way (but this is 1 at a time ~ I need to be able to use a list with variables at once):

```
df$mood <-mapply(valueFiller, df$mood)
df
```

My function doesn't work. Please help with this implementation. There may be a better way to do this, and would love to hear it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fct_recode` from the [forcats](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/index.html) package, passing a "named character vectors where the name gives the new level, and the value gives the old level":

```r
library(forcats)

df <- tibble::tibble(
  id=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50,60),
  gender=c('male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female', ''),
  mood=c('happy', 'sad', 'happy', 'sad','happy', ''),
  outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0,1),
  province = c('gp', 'np','ec','', 'wc', 'nw'))

forcats::fct_recode(df$province, "Unknown" = "")
#> [1] gp      np      ec      Unknown wc      nw     
#> Levels: Unknown ec gp np nw wc
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Wrapping this inside a `dplyr::mutate()` call will let you apply it to multiple variables at once:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tibble(
  id=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50,60),
  gender=c('male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'female', ''),
  mood=c('happy', 'sad', 'happy', 'sad','happy', ''),
  outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0,1),
  province = c('gp', 'np','ec','', 'wc', 'nw'))


df %>% 
  mutate(across(c(gender, mood, province),
                ~ forcats::fct_recode(.x, "Unknown" = "")))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>      id gender  mood    outcome province
#>   <dbl> <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <fct>   
#> 1    10 male    happy         1 gp      
#> 2    20 female  sad           1 np      
#> 3    30 female  happy         0 ec      
#> 4    40 male    sad           0 Unknown 
#> 5    50 female  happy         0 wc      
#> 6    60 Unknown Unknown       1 nw
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

For older `dplyr` versions (prior to v1.0.0), you can also use `mutate_at` (NB: you can still use this in newer versions but is has been superseded by `across` in v1.0.0):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(c("gender", "mood", "province"),
            ~ forcats::fct_recode(.x, "Unknown" = ""))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>      id gender  mood    outcome province
#>   <dbl> <fct>   <fct>     <dbl> <fct>   
#> 1    10 male    happy         1 gp      
#> 2    20 female  sad           1 np      
#> 3    30 female  happy         0 ec      
#> 4    40 male    sad           0 Unknown 
#> 5    50 female  happy         0 wc      
#> 6    60 Unknown Unknown       1 nw
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I'm getting an error: Warning message:
"package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.3"
Error in across(c(gender, mood, province), ~forcats::fct_recode(.x, Unknown = "")): could not find function "across"
Traceback:

1. df %>% mutate(across(c(gender, mood, province), ~forcats::fct_recode(.x, 
 .     Unknown = "")))

Comment: Does this mean I need a different version of R to run this successfully?

Comment: `across` was introduced in dplyr v1.0.0 which in turn depends on R >= 3.3.0. Try running `install.packages("dplyr")` to install the latest version. You can also use `dplyr::mutate_at()` (I have updated my answer accordingly).

Comment: Thanks buddy. This get's me closer to where I want to be!